# How to use analogWrite() on multiple pins at the same time?

Tags: arduino, embedded, arduino-uno, arduino-ide

I would like to do,

`analogWrite(3,100);
 analogWrite(6,200);`

at the same time. But the problem is that only the led on pin 3 lights up. I want both to light up at the same time. I've heard about direct port manipulation, but I can only find an alternate for `digitalWrite()` but I couldn't find one for `analogWrite()`. Can someone please help me with just a simple example on just how to do the above operation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Arduino has a port manipulation function. To turn both pin 3 and 5 on at the same time, do

```
DDRD = B11111110; //set pins 1-7 as output EXCEPT for 0 AT THE SAME TIME
PORTD = B00101000; // sets digital pins 5 and 3 HIGH AT THE SAME TIME
PORTD = B00000000; // sets all digital pins LOW AT THE SAME TIME
```

AnalogWrite works by PWM, so you can just toggle those with a delay that depends on the desired output voltage. Note that you can't use this method to turn on, let's say, pins 2 and 12 at the same time, because they're in different registers. I'm sure that if you browse around in your arduino folder, you'll find a C/C++ file containing the definition for analogWrite. Just take that copy it, and replace digitalWrite with the port manipulation functions below. Hope this helps!

Comment: Of course, it may just be a blown microcontroller, a broken LED, faulty wiring, etc.

Answer (score 0):

It's `analogWrite(pin, value)` not `analogWrite(value, pin)` as you're using it.
Swapping those numbers should solve your problem.

See https://cdn.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/analog-io/analogWrite/

Answer (score 0):

The code you are using is fine, and should set pin 3 to 39% power and pin 6 to 78% power using pulse width modulation. analogWrite() takes a number between 0 (off) and 255 (on).

You should check if your pins and your LEDs are working properly. You can do so by swapping both LEDs, as you already know your pin 3 and its LED are working fine.

Your pin 6 or the LED may be broken or burnt, or you could be using a LED at pin 6 that needs more current or voltage to turn on.

Answer (score -1):

You could come across this situation if you forget to set `pinMode` in setup:

```c
pinMode(3, OUTPUT);
pinMode(6, OUTPUT);
```